# How to split a polygon into multiple small parts by grid

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, vector-grid

we delineated a river basin in shape file and generated a line-featured shapefile using Hawths tools.

now our task is that we want to divide this basin into small polygons by gird in order to compute the area within the grid at the boundary. Does anyone know how to implement this using arcgis 9.3? Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

1. If your grid is a raster convert it to a polygon feature class (fc)
2. Use the [Split tool](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Split_%28Analysis%29) (or ET GeoWizard [Split by Location tool](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/et_geowizards_userguide.htm)) to create multiple fc by the split attribute
3. Use [Merge tool](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Merge_%28Data_Management%29) to merge mutiple fc to one fc